# Updating custom settings fields from XML

Tags: custom-object, customsetting, xml, mavensmate

Is it possible with Mavensmate to update fields from the XML on a custom settings object? I updated the .object file and in Mavensmate hit deploy to server. It seems that Salesforce did not to apply my changes.

Comment: MavensMate is no longer being actively developed or supported. If your need is to use xml and create fields in salesforce then I would suggest investing time in playing with Ant Migration tool.
 
Ref: https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MM uses the same API as every other tool out there for updating metadata (the Metadata API). As such, it is expected that it should work correctly. Check your "Deployment Status" history in your organization (Setup > Deploy > Deployment Status) to review your deployment history to make sure the elements you expected to deploy actually did.

Comment: So MM does say it updated and the deployment status is showing the same 4 objects were successful. However, when I go into the custom settings space, the new fields aren't showing up.

Comment: Does the custom settings object have to be public, not protected?

Comment: @DanielA.White Protected/Public only matters for managed packages, and has nothing to do with deployments. You might need to check your project's package.xml to make sure the new fields were actually in the package.xml, or that the custom setting object itself is listed as a CustomObject.